# javafx change textField value when toggle group changes

Tags: javafx

I have 3 `ToggleGroups`, which I need to attach to a `TextField`, so that the `TextField` display the appropriate number each time the `ToggleGroup` property changes.
first I've added a listener to each `ToggleGroup` as that

```
int f; //to calculate the first property condition
group1.selectedToggleProperty().addListener((v, oldValue, newValue) -> {
        if (group1.getSelectedToggle() != null) {
            //call a method which test the radioButtons to give the value to each one
            f = testChoix(rdF1, rdF2, rdF3, rdF4);
        }
    });
```

then I've added a listener to the `TextField`

```
txtCriticite.textProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
        calculCriticite();//method to calculate
    });

 //method to calculate the textField Value
 public void calculCriticite() {
    int c = f * g * d;
    txtCriticite.setText(String.valueOf(c));
}
```

when compiling and clicking on the `RadioButtons`, I don't see any text in my `TextField`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't change the text of your `TextField` inside the listener of the `TextField`, this can lead to problems. Instead, call your `calculCriticite()` method from the `ToggleGroup` listener, this should work.